# Application crashes while attempting to take a picture

Tags: android, crash, camera

I have 2 problems with my app:

-it crashes when taking a picture
-it crashes when I rotate the device

cameraPreview.java:

```
 public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
     Camera camera;
     SurfaceView preview;
     SurfaceHolder holder;
     LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_preview);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface1);
        holder = preview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        //holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);  }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    {
        Camera camera = Camera.open();      
        Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

        if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

        if(camera!=null)
        {
            try 
            {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            camera.startPreview();
            }}

          public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
          {

          }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        if(camera!=null)
        { 
            camera.stopPreview(); 
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null); 
            camera.release();       
            camera=null; 
        }
    }

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback()
    {
         @Override
         public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) 
         {
             Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
         }
    };

    public void take_picture_onClick(View view)
    {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, myPictureCallback_JPG);
    }   }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.paparazzi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".CameraPreview"
            android:configChanges="orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

At first i thought that the second issue might be caused by lack of this part:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
    if(camera!=null)
    { 
        camera.stopPreview(); 
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null); 
        camera.release();       
        camera=null; 
    }
}
```

But nothing changed after adding it.

As for the first issue I have no idea what's wrong. The app was tested on 3 different devices. I would appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT

Ok, so I'm trying to get the logs as suggested, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
public void take_picture_onClick(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

                try {
                    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logfile4.log"); 
                    filename.createNewFile(); 
                    String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }
```

The log file is created, but it is empty, even though I give it a moment to load.

Comment: Where is the logcat error report?

Comment: How can I get this report if I'm running the app on the device? I thought it's only possible on emulator, sorry.

Comment: You can instead write logs on sdcard, via file writing mechanism. Without logs it is tough to point out error.

Comment: But If you have the device, you can enable usb debugging in it and connect it to your system rite?

Comment: I tried to use usb debugging, but the system doesn't recognise the device ;(. So I just copy the .apk file onto device and install it manually.

Comment: Did you install device drivers? Maybe this is the reason why system doesn't recognize it? For logs you can use, eg. aLogcat app from Google Play.

Comment: I attempted to install drivers as described here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html , but no luck. The system can't find driver in the given location (Win 7). So far I had nothing but problems with android development :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the second issue was caused by this part (i think)

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
int height) 
{
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

camera should be a field rather than being created every time surfaceChanged is called. It works fine now.

EDIT
Actually, taking pictures works fine as well. Thank you for your suggestions.